# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable was corrupted

Tags: c

I've already saw some questions here at stackoverflow but none of them has solved my problem...

i have that code in C:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    char str[] = "";
    scanf("%[^\n]", str);
    printf("Você digitou: %s\n", str);
    system("pause");
}
```

---

When i run the program, i had the error:

Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'str' was corrupted.

now, i really don't know what i'm doing wrong there... :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The array `str` can only hold a single `char` given its initialisation. The call to `scanf()` will be overwriting the bounds the `str` causing undefined behaviour, in this case corrupting the stack. You need to decide how large the `str` array should be and limit the number of characters read to prevent buffer overrun.

To use `scanf()` you specify the maximum number of characters to read:

```
char str[1024];
if (1 == scanf("%1023[^\n]", str)) /* Check return value to ensure */
{                                  /* 'str' populated.             */
}                                  /* Specify one less than 'str'  */
                                   /* size to leave space for null.*/
```

You could also use [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) but would need to remove the new-line character afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You should not overwrite a constant with user input. Replace `char str[] = ""` with `char * str = malloc(<enough bytes for any possible input)` or even learn about safer APIs.

Answer (score 1):

You're only allocating one byte to store the input.  The line

```
char str[] = "";
```

Allocates zero bytes for the string contents and one byte for its null terminator.  Instead, do something like

```
char str[100];
```

Or whatever the maximum input length will be.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for everyone that came to C++ from Java/C# or some other modern Object Oriented language.

For me this issue happened for the following reason:

I created my own custom C++ class.

**MyClass.h**

```
class MyClass {

public:
    void work();

};
```

**MyClass.cpp**

```
#include "MyClass.h"
#include <iostream>

class MyClass{
    int64 propA, propB;

    public:
        void work();

};

void MyClass::work() {
    // some work that uses propA and propB
}
```

My intuition was that `propA` and `propB` will simply be private properties, invisible from the code outside this class.

The problem turned out to be that I haven't put `propA` and `propB` in `MyClass.h`.
Compiler doesn't know how much memory it should allocate when `MyClass` is getting instantiated by callers.

I simply added the properties to the header `MyClass.h`:

**MyClass.h (fixed)**

```
class MyClass {
    int64 propA, propB;

public:
    void work();

};
```